# post_title is empty on global $post object

Tags: plugin-development

My plugin uses publish_post hook to get the post data and do some processing:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'publish_post');

function publish_post($post_id) {
      global $post, $blog_id;
      $author = get_userdata ($post->post_author);
      $title = $post->post_title;
      //some processing here...
}
```

I notice that for a new post, $title is always blank, while all other fields are available.  If I publish the post again (update), then the title becomes available.

**Edit**

I printed out the $post variable and notice that that the post_status is draft:

```
[post_title] =>
[post_excerpt] =>
[post_status] => draft
```

So it seems the $post variable contains what was loaded from the database, but not what is currently on the screen.  How should I get the $post that reflects what is currently on the screen?  Is there a hook that fires after a post is saved to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hook is called like this:

```
do_action("{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post);
```

My guess is that you should be using data passed as second `$post` argument, rather than global.

So:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'publish_post', 10, 2 );

function publish_post($post_id, $post) {

    // stuff
```